# Алгоритм Краскала

Tags: графы

В англоязычное [википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) нашел следующее описание алгоритма на псевдо-коде:

*The following code is implemented with disjoint-set data structure:*

```
KRUSKAL(G):
1 A = ∅
2 foreach v ∈ G.V:
3   MAKE-SET(v)
4 foreach (u, v) ordered by weight(u, v), increasing:
5    if FIND-SET(u) ≠ FIND-SET(v):
6       A = A ∪ {(u, v)}
7       UNION(u, v)
8 return A
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Что здесь такое **u** и для чего нужно в цикле производить MAKE-SET(v) и что такое лес?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если непонятно - лучше почитать на русском ([вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0), [ИТМО](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0)). Так будет легче соотнести псевдокод с алгоритмом. Прокомментирую псевдокод:

```
KRUSKAL(G):
// изначально остовное дерево пустое
1 A = ∅
// каждую вершину исходного графа (обычно множество вершин обозначают буквой V, а множество рёбер - E)...
2 foreach v ∈ G.V:
// ...помещаем в своё поддерево
3   MAKE-SET(v)
// перебираем рёбра исходного графа, отсортированные по возрастанию веса
4 foreach (u, v) ordered by weight(u, v), increasing:
// если ребро (u, v) (здесь u и v обозначают две вершины графа, соединённые ребром) соединяет вершины из разных поддеревьев...
5    if FIND-SET(u) ≠ FIND-SET(v):
// ...то добавляем ребро (u, v) в остовное дерево...
6       A = A ∪ {(u, v)}
// ...и объединяем поддеревья, которым принадлежат вершины u и v в одно
7       UNION(u, v)
// после перебора всех вершин у нас получается минимальное остовное дерево.
8 return A
```

Comment: // если ребро (u, v) (здесь u и v обозначают две вершины графа, соединённые ребром) соединяет вершины из разных поддеревьев...
подскажите пожалуйста что в данном случае является поддеревом?

Comment: @Jeremen1 в алгоритме Краскала мы собираем минимальное остовное дерево из его поддеревьев. Новым ребром `(u,v)` мы создаем новое поддерево из двух поддеревьев: поддерево, содержащее `u`, и поддерево, содержащее `v`. Эти поддеревья мы храним в виде СНМ — [Системы Непересекающихся Множеств](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Дискретная математика, алгоритмы и структуры данных#Система непересекающихся множеств).